# Determine whether the integral is convergent or divergent. $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} 7xe^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

Determine whether the integral is convergent or divergent. $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} 7xe^{-x^2}dx$

It equals zero. Yet, I am unsure if it is convergent or divergent. Can someone tell me and explain why?

Comment: An integral from $\infty$ to $\infty$ does not make much sense. Did you mean $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, please look at my correction .

Comment: Once you know it converges, it is equal to 0 because it is an odd function over a symmetric interval.   Convergence as per below

Comment: A definite integral is convergent if and only if it's equal to a real number. In this case, it's equal to $0$, therefore it's convergent.

Comment: @user236182 "A definite integral is convergent if and only if it's equal to a real number.": completely meaningless sentence.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi Please explain why?

Comment: @Cetshwayo What is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x dx$? $x \mapsto x$ is an odd function, yet the integral isn't convergent for any reasonable definition of "convergent".

Comment: @Najib Idriss so what is a hard rule I should follow?

Comment: Until you know that the integral is convergent, it's too early to say that it equals zero. If it's divergent, it doesn't equal anything; it's simply just divergent.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

The indefinite integral

$$\int 7xe^{-x^2}\,dx=-\frac72 e^{-x^2}+C$$

and the limit

$$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty }e^{-x^2}=0$$